# Node.js application exits (crash) without catchable errors/signals on SQLite3 database connection close

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

The error seems to occur with connection.close and connection.run executed close to each other when the run call is in a setInterval/setTimeout or other callbacks.

See the index.js sample file
Run it with simple command "node index.js". Try to run several times.

```
//
// Nodejs version: 8.9.1
// Os version: Windows 7 64 bit (Intel i7)
// Dependencies: "sqlite3": "^4.0.2" (but it occurs also in version 3.x.x)

// Problem: one in around ten executions using "node index.js" the     application exits without signals, errors and is not possible to catch the     error/exit

var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

setInterval(function(){
    console.log("Application tick!");           //this should prevent application finish
}, 1000);

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log("uncaughtException", err);
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', function (err) {
    console.log("unhandledRejection", err);
});

process.on('rejectionHandled', function(promise) {
    console.log("rejectionHandled");
    unhandledRejections.delete(promise);
});

process.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log("exit", code);
});

setInterval(function(){
    db.run("FAKE SQL STMT", (err) => {          //the sql stmt is not important. The error occurs with both a real and correct stmt or with this fake stmt
        console.log("Sql error: " + err);
    });
}, 0);

db.close((err) => {
    console.log("Close error: " + err);
});
```

Comment: what error you're getting when your app crashes ?

Comment: From command line tools no errors. The application exits silently. If i run from IDE like webstorm i have "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Comment: Please share screenshot of what program outputs in console. Also you may try using this instead of regular import `var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();`. Maybe it will give you more information.

Comment: Here there is the console output [link](https://ibb.co/kqLJKp). Try several times.

Comment: Am I missing something? You're closing the database and executing `db.run` in an infinite loop. The node process will eventually run out of memory and simply crash. It would not have the resources to crash *gracefully*.

Comment: It is not a memory problem because when it crashes it crashes directly (after 1 second more or less). If it doesn't crash it runs without problems printing error messages due to the fact that the database is closed.